# Each page showing Favorite button and button to be saved locally to reload whenever the app restarted to see the last status page by page

Tags: sqlite, flutter, state

I need help for favorite button; is anyone help me for that?
I have pageViews and favorite buttons. Buttons are working but when I favorited one page all others are also favorited.
I recorded all favorite pages to another page and showing as listView. I can delete them as well from listView item by item.
I am fetching json data from API and recording locally to work on. In addition to that, I need to save each page's favorite status locally to reload them whenever the app restarted.

I checked lost of examples, but found too complicated since I am new. I need brief and simple example to study on it.
If you help me for that it would be appreciated.

'''

```
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: ApiProvider().getData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else {
        _itemLength = snapshot.data.length;
        _isFavorited = List<int>.generate(_itemLength, (_) => 0);

        return PageView.builder(
          itemCount: _itemLength,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            _currentIndex = index;
            /// ========= JSON DATA  ==========================
            final data = snapshot.data[index];
            jsonId = data['id'];
            quoteId = data[quoteId];
            passTitle = data['title'].toString();
       

            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: false,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  CachedNetworkImage(
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    imageUrl: data['image_url'].toString(),
                    placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: 
                    CircularProgressIndicator()),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                
                            Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
               
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              child: IconButton(
                                  key: Key('icon_$index'),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,

                                icon: (_isFav ? Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 
                                35) : Icon(Icons.favorite_border, size: 35)),
                                       color: Colors.red[500],

                                onPressed: () {
                                  print('_isFavorited onPressed  : 
                                  $_isFavorited');
                                  {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (_isFav == true) {
                                        _isFav = false;
                                        print('Favorite changed to: Off');
                                        isFavorite = _isFavorited[index] = 0;

                                        setState(() {
                                          dbHelper.deleteQuote(jsonId);
                                           

                                          _showSnackBar(context, "Favorite 
                                          Quote deleted");
                                        });

                                      } else {
                                        _isFav = true;  
                                        debugPrint('Favorite On');
                                        isFavorite = _isFavorited[index] = 1;
                                        var quote = Quote(quoteId, passTitle, 
                                        jsonId, isFavorite);
                                          
                                        dbHelper.saveQuote(quote);
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }
                                }
                              ),

                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Container(child: Text(data['title'], style: 
                  GoogleFonts.satisfy(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 
                  FontWeight.bold), key: Key('text_$index'))),

                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

'''

Comment: Can you also provide your code?

Comment: I added related code piece above. Thanks in advance for your support.